# Airplay output from RemoteIO pass through

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio, airplay, remoteio

To prove a concept I am trying to output the iDevice microphone over Airplay. I have modified the AurioTouch code to provide the pass through, and it works fine using Airplay Mirroring from 4S / iPad 2 to Apple TV.

However, when I try to use standard Airplay, either from iPhone 4 / iPad 1 or to an Airport Express, the audio outputs from the device speaker, even if the Airplay device is selected using either the system output route selector or the `MPVolumeView` in my app.

Is there anything I need to do to enable Airplay on my AudioUnit? According to the documentation:

> AirPlay support is built in to the AV Foundation framework and the Core Audio family of frameworks. Any audio content you play using these frameworks is automatically made eligible for AirPlay distribution. Once the user chooses to play your audio using AirPlay, it is routed automatically by the system.

But I don't seem to be having any joy.

Comment: Just wondering if you had any luck sorting this out. Also, how did you add the pass through in the first place?